# adequate sampling frequency in measuring acoustic emission

Tags: sampling

I am measuring acoustic emission signals. The `a.e.` frequency range is 20kHz to 1 MHz. The sampling frequency that I,set was 100kHz
Samples per second. I must be able to detect a maximum of 50 kHz signal using it. But when I do fft I get a maximum of only 300Hz.

Can anyone tell me where I would have gone wrong?

Comment: Could you please use scientific/powers of 10 notation for your frequencies, life is too short to waste it counting zeros in numbers.

Comment: or units MHz and kHz, or grouping

Answer (score 2):

How are you determining your maximum frequency?

If you sample at $f_s$ the frequency resolution (the frequency difference between frequency components) of your FFT is $f_s/N$, where $N$ is the number of samples collected. And the maximum resolvable frequency is the Nyquist frequency corresponding to the sample rate. For more information [see here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372416B-01/svtconcepts/fft_funda/)